# Cómo listar en PHP todos los productos de un catálogo con categorías sin base de datos?

Tags: php, condiciones, objeto

Estoy empezando un proyecto de e-commerce con PHP, por ahora sin usar base de datos, sino objetos (*los datos de los productos salen de un JSON*).

Los productos tienen una categoría determinada, y hay una extra llamada "**todos**" que ninguno tiene, pero sí es un parámetro en el link del menú.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?pag=productos&rama=todos">Todos</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?pag=productos&rama=cartomagia">Cartomagia</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?pag=productos&rama=manipulacion">Manipulación</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?pag=productos&rama=mentalismo">Mentalismo</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Estoy queriendo mostrar un catálogo de productos con sus categorías, pero dándole la posibilidad al usuario de poder ver todos los productos de la tienda también si lo desea.

Logré hacer que se muestren los productos con sus categorías correspondientes, pero al hacer el condicional para listar todos el código se pisa: muestra todos los productos incluso cuando elijo listar por una categoría determianda.

Alguna idea de cuál podría ser el error?

```
/** Devuelve el catálogo completo de productos que pertenecen a una determinada rama
 * @param string $rama será un string con el nombre de la rama a buscar 
 * @return Efecto[] será un array que contiene las instancias del objeto Efecto
 */

public function devolverProductoPorRama(string $rama): array
{

    $producto = [];

    // Traigo los objetos Efecto del catálogo de Json

    $catalogo = $this->mostrarCatalogoCompleto();


    foreach ($catalogo as $efectoProducto) {

        if ($efectoProducto->rama == "todos") {
            
           $catalogo = $this-> mostrarCatalogoCompleto();
        }else{
            $producto[]= $efectoProducto;
        }

        /*
        if (($efectoProducto->rama == $rama)) {

            $producto[] = $efectoProducto;

        }  */
    }
    return $producto;
}
```

Las últimas líneas del código comentadas son las que muestran correctamente los productos con sus categorías correspondientes.
Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo así:

```php
/** Devuelve el catálogo completo de productos que pertenecen a una determinada rama
 * @param string $rama será un string con el nombre de la rama a buscar 
 * @return Efecto[] será un array que contiene las instancias del objeto Efecto
 */

public function devolverProductoPorRama(string $rama): array
{
    // Traigo los objetos Efecto del catálogo de Json
    $catalogo = $this->mostrarCatalogoCompleto();

    // Si queremos mostrar todos, devolvemos todos
    if ($rama == 'todos') return $catalogo;

    // Sino....
    $productos = [];
    foreach ($catalogo as $efectoProducto) {
        // Si es de la misma rama
        if (($efectoProducto->rama == $rama)) {
            $productos[] = $efectoProducto;
        }
    }
    return $productos;
}
```

Comment: Marcos muchísimas gracias!!! Me sirve mucho!